# Ramda: get objects from array by comparing with each item in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ramda.js

I've an array like:

```
ids = [1,3,5];
```

and another array like:

```
items: [
{id: 1, name: 'a'}, 
{id: 2, name: 'b'}, 
{id: 3, name: 'c'}, 
{id: 4, name: 'd'}, 
{id: 5, name: 'e'}, 
{id: 6, name: 'f'}
];
```

What I want is another array like:

```
array = [{id: 1, name: 'a'}, {id: 3, name: 'c'}, {id: 5, name: 'e'}];
```

I can't get my head around it. so far i tried like:

```
console.log(R.filter(R.propEq('id', <donnow what shud be here>), items);
console.log( R.pick(ids)(items))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you still want to do with Ramda:

```js
const ids = [1,3,5];

const items = [
{id: 1, name: 'a'}, 
{id: 2, name: 'b'}, 
{id: 3, name: 'c'}, 
{id: 4, name: 'd'}, 
{id: 5, name: 'e'}, 
{id: 6, name: 'f'}
];

console.log(

  R.filter(R.compose(R.flip(R.contains)(ids), R.prop('id')), items)

);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). Note these are ECMA5 methods for Arrays, and will not work in IE8.

```
var ids = [1, 3, 5];
var items = [
  {id: 1, name: 'a'}, 
  {id: 2, name: 'b'}, 
  {id: 3, name: 'c'}, 
  {id: 4, name: 'd'}, 
  {id: 5, name: 'e'}, 
  {id: 6, name: 'f'}
];

var filtered = items.filter(function(obj) {
  return ids.indexOf(obj.id) > -1;
});
console.log(filtered); // [{id: 1, name: 'a'}, {id: 3, name: 'c'}, {id: 5, name: 'e'}];
```

Comment: This is correct! You will however need to add a polyfill if you are targeting IE8 and below

Answer (score 4):

Or may be one liner without Ramda

```
items.filter(x=>ids.includes(x.id))
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a hash table for faster lookup.

```js
var ids = [1, 3, 5],
    items = [{id: 1, name: 'a'}, {id: 2, name: 'b'}, {id: 3, name: 'c'}, {id: 4, name: 'd'}, {id: 5, name: 'e'}, {id: 6, name: 'f'} ],
    filtered = items.filter(function(obj) {
        return this[obj.id];
    }, ids.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a] = true;
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null)));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filtered, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: This is quite useful when you have a large collection and/or when you want to curry the ids into a reusable function.  I probably wouldn't accept the overhead of creating that temporary structure otherwise.

Comment: Also, while I usually find your code quite easy to read, something about the indentation here seems off.  `Object.create...` looks to be a third parameter to `filter`.

Comment: you are right, the formatting is wrong, but today i wouls write it with a `Set` instead (as variable, not as `thisArg`).

Comment: Yes, I had somehow missed that this was an old post when it came to my attention today.  Sorry about that.