# Filter object array based on another - Ramda functional style

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

```
let arr = [
{
 id: 100,
 name: 'bmw'
},
{
 id: 101,
 name" 'porsche'
}
];

let selected = [{id: 100}];
```

What is the Ramda way of getting a filtered list F based on the inputs (list, selected)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37091448/ramda-get-objects-from-array-by-comparing-with-each-item-in-another-array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ramda has a function built-in which directly handles finding the single value.  If you want to find all the ones in a list, you'll need to extend it a bit.  But [`whereEq`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#whereEq) tests an object to see if all the properties match those in a sample object.  So you can do something like this:

```js
const {find, whereEq, map} = R;

const arr = [
  {id: 100, name: 'bmw'},
  {id: 101, name: 'porsche'},
  {id: 102, name: 'ferrari'},
  {id: 103, name: 'clunker'}
]

console.log(find(whereEq({id: 101}), arr))

const choose = (all, selected) => map(sel => find(whereEq(sel), all), selected)

console.log(choose(arr, [{id: 101}, {id: 103}]))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Depending upon how you plan to use it, you might want to wrap `choose` in [`curry`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#curry).

Answer (score 1):

My take would be to break it down into a few parts.

```
// a function to grab the the id out of selected (index of 0, key of 'id')
const selectedId = path([0, 'id'])

const selectedValue = (selected, options) =>
  filter(propEq('id', selectedId(selected)), options)

selectedValue(selected, arr) // [{"id": 100, "name": "bmw"}]
```

That’s a little difficult to read for my liking, so I’d then regroup some of the functions, and also use `head` to get the result out of the array

```
const hasIdOf = pipe(selectedId, propEq('id'))

const selectedValueB = (selected, options) => pipe(
  filter(hasIdOf(selected))),
  head
)(options)

selectedValueB(selected, arr) // {"id": 100, "name": "bmw"}
```

`propEq(‘id’)` returns a function that takes two more parameters. A value to test an `id` property against, and an object with an `id` property

`pipe` composes many functions together, in this case, it’s passing `options` to `filter(...)`, and the result of that to `head`

`head` returns item at index 0

You can break up the functions in many ways. Whatever you find most readable/reusable

[Have a play with the above code here](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?let%20arr%20%3D%20%5B%0A%7B%0A%20id%3A%20100%2C%0A%20name%3A%20%27bmw%27%0A%7D%2C%0A%7B%0A%20id%3A%20101%2C%0A%20name%3A%20%27porsche%27%0A%7D%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Alet%20selected%20%3D%20%5B%7Bid%3A%20100%7D%5D%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20a%20function%20to%20grab%20the%20the%20id%20out%20of%20selected%20%28index%20of%200%2C%20key%20of%20%27id%27%29%0Aconst%20selectedId%20%3D%20path%28%5B0%2C%20%27id%27%5D%29%0A%0Aconst%20selectedValue%20%3D%20%28selected%2C%20options%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20filter%28propEq%28%27id%27%2C%20selectedId%28selected%29%29%2C%20arr%29%0A%0AselectedValue%28selected%2C%20arr%29%20%2F%2F%20%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%20100%2C%20%22name%22%3A%20%22bmw%22%7D%5D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20or%20break%20it%20down%20one%20step%20more%20and%20get%20the%20head%0Aconst%20byId%20%3D%20propEq%28%27id%27%29%0Aconst%20idOf%20%3D%20selectedId%0A%0Aconst%20hasIdOf%20%3D%20pipe%28selectedId%2C%20propEq%28%27id%27%29%29%0A%0Aconst%20selectedValueB%20%3D%20%28selected%2C%20options%29%20%3D%3E%20pipe%28%0A%20%20filter%28hasIdOf%28selected%29%29%2C%0A%20%20head%0A%29%28options%29%0A%0AselectedValueB%28selected%2C%20arr%29)

Comment: Oh boy, I don't have enough reputation to upvote or comment on Scott's answer :O But I certainly learned something new there. Thanks Scott.