# Use Ramda to map an array of ids to objects with those ids

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

How can I map an array of ids:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

to their corresponding objects in another array:

```
[
  {
    id: 'a',
    label: 'Letter A'
  },
  {
    id: 'b',
    label: 'Letter B'
  },
  ...
  ...
]
```

The other array is likely to have more objects than the first array has ids.

The challenging part is that I want to do this the "Ramda way".

If I were not using RamdaJS, it would look like this:

```
const ids = ['a', 'b']
const objects = [{ id: 'a', label: 'Letter A' }, { id: 'b', label: 'Letter B' }, { id: 'c', label: 'Letter C' }]
const whatIWant = objects.filter(obj => ids.includes(obj.id))
```

There must be a way to do this with a combination of `map`, `filter`, `prop`, `propEq`, `isNil`, `reject`, etc. I just can't seem to figure it out.

"Keep/filter the objects who have ids included in the ids array"

I know the following code doesn't work, but this is sort of how far I got:

```
const doFilter = (ids, objects) => (
  map(
    find(
      // ??? Where the object.id is included in ids[]
    )(objects)
  )(ids)
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37091448/ramda-get-objects-from-array-by-comparing-with-each-item-in-another-array)

```js
const ids = ['a', 'b'];
const objects = [{ id: 'a', label: 'Letter A' }, { id: 'b', label: 'Letter B' }, { id: 'c', label: 'Letter C' }];
console.log(R.flip(R.contains)(ids)('a'));
console.log(R.flip(R.contains)(ids)('c'));
console.log(R.filter(R.compose(R.flip(R.contains)(ids), R.prop('id')), objects));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

---

[ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50161078/filter-collection-based-on-values-in-array-in-ramda)

```js
const ids = ['a', 'b'];
const objects = [{ id: 'a', label: 'Letter A' }, { id: 'b', label: 'Letter B' }, { id: 'c', label: 'Letter C' }];

const joinById = R.innerJoin(
  (o, id) => o.id === id
);

const result = joinById(objects, ids);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Good job finding out these previous questions! I'm tempted to close this one as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Using `map` to exclude items from a list was probably a bad start. You typically use `map` to transform items (not exclude them):

```
map(add(1), [10,20,30]);
//=> [11,21,31]
```

To exclude items from a list you have two options: `filter` or `reject`

`filter` keeps items that passed a predicate:

```
filter(equals('foo'), ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']);
//=> ['foo']
```

Whereas `reject` keeps the items that didn't:

```
reject(equals('foo'), ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']);
//=>  ['bar', 'baz']
```

---

To answer your question I'd use `flip`+`includes` with `where`.

Use `flip` to reverse the order of the arguments to `includes`. Why? You already know the list of whitelisted ids:

```
const inWhitelist = flip(includes)(['a', 'b', 'c']);
inWhitelist('a'); // true
inWhitelist('z'); // false
```

Then use `where` to query each object. With just one property to check, you could use `propSatisfies` but in general `where` reads better. (YMMV of course.)

```
filter(where({id: inWhitelist}), objects);
```

---

```js
const ids = ['a', 'b'];

const objects = [
  { id: 'a',
    label: 'Letter A' },
  { id: 'b',
    label: 'Letter B' },
  { id: 'c',
    label: 'Letter C' }];
    
const inWhitelist = flip(includes)(ids);

console.log(

  filter(where({id: inWhitelist}), objects)

)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {filter, where, flip, includes} = R;</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ramda way (if you think it's more readable than vanilla js):

```js
const ids = ['a', 'b']
const objects = [
  { id: 'a', label: 'Letter A' },
  { id: 'b', label: 'Letter B' },
  { id: 'c', label: 'Letter C' },
];

const isInArray = R.flip (R.includes);

const filterByIds = ids => R.filter(R.propSatisfies(isInArray(ids), 'id'));

const results = filterByIds (ids) (objects);

console.log(results):
// [ { id: 'a', label: 'Letter A' },
//   { id: 'b', label: 'Letter B' } ];
```